# Using google translate shell and set bash alias

Tags: bash

I am using google translate shell CLI command "**trans 'words' -speak**" to display the translation and use a command of "**trans 'words' >> my_file** " to save the translation into a file; when I try to merge two commands by "**trans 'words" -speak  >>  my_file**" or "**trans 'words'｜tee -a my_file**", but it doesn't work!!

Comment: "failed" is not a sufficient error description.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:
create a bin folder and make an alias to that script

```
mkdir bin
cd bin
nano script_name 
place commands in script => #!/bin/bash; /path/to/trans -speak | tee -a "$1"
chmod a+x script_name
set alias to script_name
```

login and type  script_name "/path/to/file"